# Using ssl in Ingress without cert-manager

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ovh, cert-manager

I'm trying to uses ssl in several Ingress on k8s. A first look up lead me to [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/) but I can't make it work and I suspect that the cause is because my Cloud provider ([ovh](https://www.ovh.com/fr/)) is not supported.

I'm using **kubernetes 1.17** and **cert-manager 0.13.0**

The first error I encountered was related to the [web hook secret](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/2484) and no solutions worked for me.

Because of this I deployed [cert-manager without web-hook](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/compatibility/) but I still couldn't get a ClusterIssuer up and running. When I apply the following :

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  acme:
    email: leonard.panichi@gmail.com
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

a clusterissuer is created but there is no Status when I run describe on it.

So, after new searches (and more than a day of struggling), I found that [ovh might not be compatible with cert-manager](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/694)
which let me think that I'm loosing my time with this strategy.
Hence I'm looking for a new strategy.

How can I use certbot, there is a docker image [certbot/certbot](https://hub.docker.com/r/certbot/certbot/), to create and renew a few ssl certificates in kubernetes secrets in order to use them in my Ingress ? Is there any other way that do not requiere GKE, AWS, something simple, portable, production ready, etc...

Sincerely,
me

Comment: If using [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/https/acme/) is an option for you, you can drop cert-manager alltogether.

Comment: Have you tried this? [Certs](https://medium.com/@mathieu.naouache/why-i-created-certs-an-alternative-to-cert-manager-396d2ce13cca)

Comment: Based on the link you have provided, your issue is not with your cloud Kubernetes provider; instead, OVH is not a supported DNS provider. You can consider moving your DNS to a supported DNS provider (eg. CloudFlare, AWS, GCP). `cert-manager` application should be portable and just needs a supported Kubernetes version. However, to issue SSL certs, it needs to dynamically create DNS records, hence the need for cloud DNS support.